# Why is the set of units of integer quaternions isomorphic to the quaternion group of order 8?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, normed-spaces, quaternions, group-isomorphism

Let's say that I've got a ring $V$ of integer quaternions of the form $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}i  + \mathbb{Z}j + \mathbb{Z}k$.  Now assume that there exists an element $a = a_1 + a_2i + a_3j + a_4k$ such that $ab=ba=1$ for some other element $b \in V$ and likewise that ${a_1}^2 + {a_2}^2 + {a_3}^2 + {a_4}^2 = 1$.  Why would this imply that the set of all such $a \in V$, called $V^\text{x}$, is isomorphic to the quaternion group of order $8$?

Comment: If you're asking why those are the only units, look at the general form of the inverse in the ring of quaternions and you'll see why. If you know why those are the units, then it's isomorphic to the quaternion group of order 8 because it *is* the quaternion group of order 8.

Comment: Hmm. So I know that the inverse in the ring of rational quaternions of a nonzero element $a$ is $ \frac{\bar{a} }{N(a)}$ and I know that $N(a) = a * \overline{a}$.   Does that mean that $a$ is its own inverse whenever it is a unit, and thus it is the only unit in the ring of quaternions? I guess my question then is what is the quaternion group of order $8$? Or is it really just defined this way?

Comment: It's not necessarily its own inverse, but anything that is not one of those 8 elements would have non-integer components in the inverse. And yes, this is really the definition of the group. If you define it some other way and it's not this particular set then it is only an isomorphic group. By abuse of language they are given the same name when the isomorphism class is the only thing that is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m guessing from your comment that you don’t know what $Q_8$ is. It has eight elements, $\{\pm1,\pm i,\pm j, \pm k\}$ with the property that $\{\pm1\}$ commute with everything, and such that $i$, $j$, and $k$ satisfy the combination rules that you know: $ij=k=-ji$, $jk=i=-kj$, and $ki=j=-ik$. Now you see it?